# Rails 5 How can I change the url from companies/:id/jobs/:id to jobs/:id

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I had the controllers : `companies` and  `jobs`, and company has_many jobs , jobs belong_to company.

Now I write the `routes.rb` like this:

```
resources :companies do
    member do
      post :star
      delete :unstar
      get :destroys
      get :jobs
    end
    resources :jobs,except: [:index]
  end
  resources :jobs,only: [:index]
```

My `jobs_controller.rb` like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user,except: [:index,:show]
  before_action :set_company,except: [:index]
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.taggables.build
    @job.company_id = @company.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html {
          redirect_to company_jobs_path(@company)
          flash[:success] = "Success"
        }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end

  end


  private

  def set_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit!
  end
end
```

I can get one job display of the company with the url such like :

"127.0.0.1:3000/companies/4/jobs/1"

But now I just want to get job url by id, just like

"127.0.0.1:3000/jobs/1"

How could I write the `routes.rb`?

Thanks for your help so much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your *routes* as below

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    post :star
    delete :unstar
    get :destroys
    get :jobs
  end
  resources :jobs,except: [:index, :show]
end
resources :jobs,only: [:index, show]
```

Comment: I had try with your codes, and then I get the error said `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Company without an ID:
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:68:in `set_company'` , what should I do ? Thanks so much.

Comment: @SylorHuang You need to change this `before_action :set_company,except: [:index]` to `before_action :set_company,except: [:index, :show]`

Comment: Thanks so much. @Pavan.

Answer (score 0):

Try using shallow nesting?

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    post :star
    delete :unstar
    get :destroys
    get :jobs # <= Are you sure this should be here?
  end
  resources :jobs, shallow: true # <= This is new
end
```

Link in Rails docs here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting